# spring deferred result response in weblogic

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, weblogic

I have implemented DeferredResult in spring MVC. It returns the right response in Tomcat8 but when I deployed into weblogic 12.1.3 gives me 404 error. I tried to debug to find out what is going on then at some point handler is looking for view in web-inf directory. I am confused here.

Could you please help me to understand?

I am using Spring

1. Java 7
2. Spring 4.2.0.RELEASE
3. Spring OAuth2
4. Weblogic 12.1.3

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/file/{id}")
   @ResponseBody
   public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<Resource>> file(@PathVariable String id) {
   DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<Resource>> result = new DeferredResult<>();

   try {
       final ImageObject image = null;
       final Resource fileResource = new FileSystemResource(image.getImagePath().replace("E:", "C:"));
       final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
       headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
       headers.setContentLength(fileResource.contentLength());
       result.setResult(new ResponseEntity<>(fileResource, headers, HttpStatus.OK));
   } catch (Exception e) {

   }

   return result;
   }
   ```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case Spring wrongly concatenated a @RequestMapping path of @RestController and @RequestMapping path of a method. @RequestMapping path of @RestController was duplicated in a resulting URI in Spring logs.

The only workaround I've found is to create @RestController**s** for each required DeferredResult method without specifying a @RequestMapping path in the methods.

WebLogic 12.2.1.3.0, Spring 4.3.23.